# POS Receipt Printing From Rails App to Star Micronics TSP 143U

Tags: ruby-on-rails, printing, receipt

Ok, this is starting to seem like a bit of a hopeless situation so I might as well throw a question out there to see if I can get lucky.  I have a star micronics TSP 143U receipt printer connected to a Lantronix xPrintServer Home Edition to enable AirPrinting to the receipt printer over the local network.  90% of the setup works perfectly -- I have a rails webapp that creates a receipt and formats it using a css print media query, the Star Printer gets plugged in via USB to the xPrintServer and is found and configured within 30 seconds automatically, and all of my iOS devices can detect the printer and initiate print jobs.  To print the job I use a javascript document.print() call on page load.

Everything works fine, EXCEPT when a print job is initiated, the printer prints what is needed and then does not stop feeding paper or cut the receipt. Is there any way I can format the HTML document using CSS to induce the printer to stop printing after the last line of text?  Alternatively, is there any way I can send an esc/p2 escape command to a printer on the local network from a mobile safari browser (according to their docs the cut command is esc d)?

Comment: Since this is a bit of an old question, things may have changed :) Did you ever find a solution to this that got it working? I'm in the same situation. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is Matt from star micronics tech support.  The tsp100 does not support print servers and the only way we support printing via usb on ios is to connect the printer to an apple airport.  In addition we don't support airprint or any web printing from ios, only from apps that were designed to work with our printers using the sdk on our website.  This could be the cause of the issue.

If you have questions please contact star tech support-800 782 7636 option 3 or email support@starmicronics.com

Answer (score 0):

I've sent this question to Lantronix support. They suggested me updating lantronix software and it worked for me. Here's tutorial: http://ltxfaq.custhelp.com/ci/fattach/get/23364/1364416067/redirect/1/filename/xPrintServer%20Firmware%20Upgrade%20Utility%20Windows_v3.pdf