# Receipt Printing not stopping

Tags: css, html, printing

I'm trying to print an HTML receipt using a Start TSP100 series printer.  The receipt is generated from our application and can be anywhere from a few lines longs to potentially hundreds.

The most similar ticket I've found on SO is: [POS Receipt Printing From Rails App to Star Micronics TSP 143U](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119388/pos-receipt-printing-from-rails-app-to-star-micronics-tsp-143u) expect that we are not using print servers, just printing a web page.

I've narrowed it down to trying to print a static web page (no styles, or fonts) and have even tried it with static text instead of html

Here is the text of receipt.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

    10/30/2014   2:23 PM<br />

    <br />

    Credit Card Sale<br />

    <br />
    Business Inc.<br />
    1001 Business Cir.<br />
    Los Angeles, Washington - 12345<br />
    ops@company.com<br />
    1231231234<br />
    <br />

    Merchant #: 1234<br />
    Terminal ID: 123<br />
    Operator ID: 123  Batch: 123<br />
    Invoice: 123<br />
    <br />

    Customer Name  : John  Smith<br />
    Card #:  : XXXXXXXXXX1234 - Manual<br />



    Invoice Total  US$ 0.00<br />
    <br />
    Approved : 12345<br />

</body>
</html>
```

And static text:
    10/30/2014   2:23 PM

```
Credit Card Sale


Business Inc.
1001 Business Cir.
Los Angeles, Washington - 12345
ops@company.com
1231231234


Merchant #: 1234
Terminal ID: 123
Operator ID: 123  Batch: 123
Invoice: 123


Customer Name  : John  Smith
Card #:  : XXXXXXXXXX1234 - Manual



Invoice Total  US$ 0.00

Approved : 12345
```

The page prints, but it does not stop printing.  Actually the page is apparently 10+ meters longs in print preview, but I always need to shut down after a few meters of paper run.  Here is what print preview looks like:

[image]

I've tried:
css page-break-before, page-break-after attributes in various locations, but this creates 2 huge pages, one before and one after the break.

I've tested on IE and Chrome but this appears to be similar to issue in the ticket I've referenced which was on iOS

The paper size has been set to "72mm x Receipt" and the test page does appear to print and stop properly.

Any ideas on what to check, or where to go from here?

Comment: Have you tried debugging in chrome with the print mime type emulation? It should give you a closer indication if there are styles that are affecting the page that are only visible when printing. +1 for saving the environment.

Comment: Can we see, what, if any, CSS you're applying to this page, please?

Comment: @JoshBurgess there is no css at all.

Comment: @TysonWolker...thanks, will try chrome print mimi type emulation

Comment: Got any solution for this issue?  I am facing same problem for a receipt print.  I don't think width is the issue.  Key problem is the print does not stop at the bottom of the text.  It continues to scroll until I switch off the printer

Answer (score 3):

After talking to tech support, it appears web printing is not supported by the TSP100 series.  They suggested using the TSP650II WebPRNT model.

A possible work-around I've found is to print at "72mm x 200mm" instead of "72mm x Receipt".  This still wastes some paper (100mm on average I suppose), but it's much better then before.

Answer (score 0):

in my printer Bixolon :
i use display inline-table.

```
 .mainPrintInside {display: inline-table; width: 100%;}
```